# Problem with pwndbg and gdb. Gdb doesn't see plugin

Tags: gdb

I learn binary exploitation recently. I was using plugin with ghidra, peda pwndbg from internet. For one week everything was perfect but I wanted add gef plugin and started to get it... Basically I deleted file with ghidra, peda and pwndbg by mistake. I wanted only to get rid of peda as I don't use it. It was super big mistake because now even after redownloading file with all three from github when I trying to use gdp-pwndbg(this one is seen as command fortunately) when hitting enter instead of active plugin pwndbg I got strange error. I will paste it here. Does anyone of you have any idea how to fix it?

I tried to delete all files and reinstall them but still got this message:

````
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/karolina2/pwndbg/gdbinit.py", line 58, in <module>
    import pwndbg  # noqa: F401
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/karolina2/pwndbg/pwndbg/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pwndbg.commands
  File "/home/karolina2/pwndbg/pwndbg/commands/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pwndbg.heap.ptmalloc import DebugSymsHeap
  File "/home/karolina2/pwndbg/pwndbg/heap/ptmalloc.py", line 20, in <module>
    import pwndbg.disasm
  File "/home/karolina2/pwndbg/pwndbg/disasm/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    "rv32": CS_ARCH_RISCV,
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   NameError: name 'CS_ARCH_RISCV' is not defined. Did you mean: 'CS_ARCH_MIPS'?
   (gdb) quit
`

```
````

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue installing pwndbg as well. It turns out I for some reason didn't have the most updated version of Python Capstone. Try running `pip install --upgrade capstone`. It fixed it for me. Credit goes to intrigus on the pwndbg Discord!